# Video Games Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, video-games

[image]

```
ACROSS      
1   God no longer (4,2)
#4  Mode of transport for an electron density of 1001 (9)
#6  No hit out (4)
7   Jill's brother is a stranger (3,3'1,4,4)
12  Wasn't Clyde Narain a mammal? (7,3)
14  Insect killer above the red square (4,4,6)
15  Helminthiasis (5)
16  Found in my stomach (4)
17  He keeps punching the pavement (6,7)
19  How to get into the hairless Sumerian city (6'1,4)
20  A rubber dog's toy shaped like a mule (6,4)
21  Excavator aroused abnormally (5,5)
23  Last dream (5,7)
27  What a smell! (4)
29  Iranian heir (6,2,6)
31  Gracelands former occupant endlessly messed up (8,4)
36  Young man with a preference for parchment (8)
38  It's the bola I'd tangled up (6)
41  Lucifer Lacrimosa (5,3,3)
43  Grey (5,3,5)
45  Proxemics offenders (5,8)
46  The grassy knoll won't tell (6,4)
48  Bad mood (4)
49  It's not doubling time (4-4)
50  Harry Potter's canine omen buys tickets in the US (4,8)
51  Seen in his naked form (5)
52  Aves aggrieved (5,5)

DOWN    
1   John Wayne takes extreme action (4,5)
2   Mr Astley takes chances (4,9)
#3  Over-enthused about icing a cake (9)
5   Overlooked planets (9,6)
8   Phoning about your shift (4,2,4)
9   Watery brontide (5,7)
10  Tents messed up by a Sumerian goddess (6)
#11 Attempts an alternative to coffee, initially confused (6)
13  It sounds like hay for a priest (6,6)
18  Podiatrist's problem with a count (6,3,4)
22  James Annelida (9,3)
24  They play for the director of a Life of Pi (7)
25  £1000 robbery without thinking (5,5,4)
26  You can't have it, that brush (11)
28  Bill is ready to fly (3,3,5)
30  A tripping skydiver does it (7)
32  It looks like Mr Hanks does hair (4,6)
33  Instructs the avian limb (4,9)
34  The french leave a cricketer (4,6)
35  Tangled ropes (5)
37  Too many sweets in your pocket (5,5)
39  Smaug + Tiamat (6,6)
40  It goes round your pebble (4,4)
42  Outcome of a religious service (4,6)
44  Simon Cowell (6)
47  Torn, broken (4)
```

Hopefully there aren't too many here that people find obscure or ambiguous. If people are struggling, I might add release dates.

Comment: Does all punctuation get its own space? For 7 across, 19 across and 49 across the number of spaces in the grid is more than the clue length.

Comment: @Fillet I should have reduced the length of those ones, but as the grid is presented, punctuation does get a space.

Comment: As you are running this, could you update the grid to show the answers that have been completed. That way we can see what's left. Thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I've marked the 4 clues that still need solving.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is now a complete solution! 
This was only possible due to the partial solutions from @Gabriel Guimarães, @Squeamish Ossifrage, @Hazel, @The Dark Truth and @Irishpanda, whose answers I copied in, and a comment by @Zandar. Of course, being a crossword, the partial solutions also gave at times prompts of additional letters.

Across

1   God no longer (4,2)

> Deus Ex. Found by @The Dark Truth

4  Mode of transport for an electron density of 1001 (9)

> Minecraft. MI is Roman numeral for 1001. n_e is the electon density in semiconductor physics. A craft can be a ship or spaceship.

6 No hit out (4)

> Sims (Anagram of Miss). Found in comment by @Zandar

7   Jill's brother is a stranger (3,3'1,4,4)

> You don't know Jack

12  Wasn't Clyde Narain a mammal? (7,3)

> Chuckie egg (Clyde Narain is DJ Chuckie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuckie_(DJ)

14  Insect killer above the red square (4,4,6)

> Raid over Moscow

15  Helminthiasis (5)

> Worms

16 Found in my stomach (4)

> Myst (**my st**omach). Found by @Gabriel Guimarães

17 He keeps punching the pavement (6,7)

> Street Fighter. Found by @Irishpanda

19 How to get into the hairless Sumerian city (6'1, 4)

> Baldur's Gate (Bald + Ur, gate). Found by @Gabriel Guimarães

20  A rubber dog's toy shaped like a mule (6,4)

> Donkey Kong

21  Excavator aroused abnormally (5,5)

> Manic Miner

23  Last dream (5,7)

> Final Fantasy

27  What a smell! (4)

> Pong

29  Iranian heir (6,2,6)

> Prince of Persia

31  Gracelands former occupant endlessly messed up (8,4)

> Resident Evil (Elvis without an "s" anagrammed)

36  Young man with a preference for parchment (8)

> Paperboy

38  It's the bola I'd tangled up (6)

> Diablo (anagram *bola I'd*)

41: Lucifer Lacrimosa (5,3,3)

> Devil may cry. Found by @The Dark Truth

43  Grey (5,3,5)

> Black and white (if you mix the paint)

45  Proxemics offenders (5,8)

> Space Invaders (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxemics)

46  The grassy knoll won't tell (6,4)

> Silent Hill

48  Bad mood (4)

> Doom (anagram of mood)

49  It's not doubling time (4-4)

> Half-Life

50  Harry Potter's canine omen buys tickets in the US (4,8)

> Grim Fandango. Found by @The Dark Truth

51  Seen in his naked form (5)

> Snake (hidden in hi**s nake**d form

52: Aves aggrieved (5,5)

> Angry Birds. Found by @squeamish ossifrage

DOWN
1   John Wayne takes extreme action (4,5)

> Duke Nukem (J.W's nickname is "the Duke")

2   Mr Astley takes chances (4,9)

> Rick Dangerous

3  Over-enthused about icing a cake (9)

> Pipemania (you can pipe icing onto a cake)

5   Overlooked planets (9,6)

> Forgotten Worlds

8   Phoning about your shift (4,2,4)

> Call of Duty

9 Watery brontide (5,7)

> Hydro Thunder. Found by @Irishpanda

10  Tents messed up by a Sumerian goddess (6)

> Pacman (camp anagrammed with An (sumerian goddess))

11 Attempts an alternative to coffee, initially confused (6)

> Tetris (*Tries* + initial letter of *Tea* anagrammed)

13  It sounds like hay for a priest (6,6)

> Cannon Fodder

18 Podiatrist's problem with a count (6,3,4)

> Toejam and Earl

22  James Annelida (9,3)

> Earthworm Jim

24 They play for the director of a Life of Pi (7)

> Angband. (Ang Lee is the director). Found by @Hazel

25  £1000 robbery without thinking (5,5,4)

> Grand Theft Auto (a Grand is slang for 1000£)

26  You can't have it, that brush (11)

> Minesweeper

28 Bill is ready to fly (3, 3, 5)

> Jet Set Willy. Found by @Gabriel.

30  A tripping skydiver does it (7)

> Fallout (of the plane)

32 It looks like Mr Hanks does hair (4,6)

> Tomb Raider (Tom Braider). Found by @sqeamish ossifrage

33  Instructs the avian limb (4,9)

> Wing Commander

34  The french leave a cricketer (4,6)

> Lego Batman (**Le** is "The" in French, **go** is to leave, and a cricketer is a bat(s)man

35  Tangled ropes (5)

> Spore (anagram of ropes)

37 Too many sweets in your pocket (5,5)

> Candy Crush. Found by @squeamish ossifrage

39  Smaug + Tiamat (6,6)

> Double Dragon (Smaug is a dragon in "The Hobbit", Tiamat is a goddess in the form of a dragon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiamat)

40 It goes round your pebble (4,4)

> Rock Band. Found by @Hazel

42  Outcome of a religious service (4,6)

> Mass Effect

44  Simon Cowell (6)

> Hitman.

47  Torn, broken (4)

> Tron (Anagram)

Comment: Good progress, but 5 down clashes with 29 across.

Comment: I made a change to 5 down, it was a bit of a guess.

Comment: Since you have more please feel free to include my few answers in yours for completeness.

Comment: @TheDarkTruth I may do this evening if I'm getting very close to a full solution, but until then I'll leave the door open you or anyone else to post a full solution with or without our combined efforts.

Comment: Since your answer is the largest, I'll leave this comment here. I want to say 11 Across is an anagram or partial anagram of TRY TEA, but I can't come up with anything meaningful from it aside from TREATY, but that doesn't seem to fit the context.

Comment: @Irishpanda I think TETRIS is the answer. Anagram of TRIES and the initial letter of T. I'll put it in.

Comment: TRIES T *head desk*

Comment: I'd imagine 6A is Sims, an anagram of "miss".

Comment: I think we have a winner!

Answer (score 4):

Across:

1: God no longer (4,2)

> Deus Ex

41: Lucifer Lacrimosa (5,3,3)

> Devil May Cry

50: Harry Potter's canine omen buys tickets in the US (4,8)

> Grim Fandango

Answer (score 4):

A few more...

ACROSS:

52: Aves aggrieved (5,5)

> Angry [Birds](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aves)

DOWN:

32: It looks like Mr Hanks does hair (4,6)

> TOMB RAIDER (Tom, braider)

37: Too many sweets in your pocket (5,5)

> Candy Crush

Answer (score 4):

Some more:

Across:

17 Found in my stomach (4)

> Myst (**my st**omach)

19 How to get into the hairless Sumerian city (6'1, 4)

> Baldur's Gate (Bald + Ur, gate)

Down:

28 Bill is ready to fly (3, 3, 5)

> Jet Set Willy

Answer (score 3):

Yet a few more:

ACROSS

17  He keeps punching the pavement (6,7)

> Street Fighter

DOWN

1   John Wayne takes extreme action (4,5)

> Duke Nukem

9   Watery brontide (5,7)

> Hydro Thunder

Answer (score 3):

Two extra:

DOWN

24  They play for the director of a Life of Pi (7)

> Angband

40  It goes round your pebble (4,4)

> Rock Band